# tensorflow object detection API ImportError when generating PASCAL TFRecord files

Tags: tensorflow, importerror, object-detection

I'm trying to use the Tensorflow Object Detection API and I've successfully tested the installation,but we I try to generate the PASCAL VOC TFRecord files with the given command

```
python object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py \
--label_map_path=object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt \
--data_dir=VOCdevkit --year=VOC2012 --set=train \
--output_path=pascal_train.record
```

I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py", line 36, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
ImportError: No module named object_detection.utils
```

my PYTHONPATH is:

```
:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/slim
```

and I'm running the above command in the /models directory,anyone who knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: I run 'from object_detection.utils import dataset_util' in the python console and it works fine. I'm really confused!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./object_detection"))
```

and

```
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
```

becomes

```
from utils import dataset_util
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to add 'object_detection' to the env path, not in the python script.

You can do this in the shell, at the 'object_detection' directory.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`
```

Or add the path to .bashrc/.zshrc (depend on your shell), so don‘t need to export every time.

```
echo "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd` >> ~/.bashrc
```