# Generating TFRecord Files

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Having installed tensorflow and the object detection module successfully, I am having trouble generating the PASCAL VOC TFRecord files as detailed in the documentation.

On running from the /models directory

```
python2 object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py  
--label_map_path=object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt  
--data_dir=VOCdevkit --year=VOC2012 --set=train 
--output_path=pascal_train.record
```

ImportError: No module named object_detection.utils

I followed the suggestion to add the object_detection to the system path as recommended on the below mentioned link. This seems to temporarily resolve the issue but throws the same import error in another file compiled by protoc. My guess is the import "from object_detection.XXX import YYY" has been used across files and it is not conceivable to make changes to all such source files.

[tensorflow object detection API ImportError when generating PASCAL TFRecord files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254975/tensorflow-object-detection-api-importerror-when-generating-pascal-tfrecord-file)

Looking forward to a resolution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the installation and package path info is clearly described [install OD tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)

```
# From tensorflow/models/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

# Also you can add the same to your ~/bashrc file as 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/absolute_path/to/tensorflow/models:/absolute/path/to/tensowflow/models/slim
```